# get HttpServletRequest object inside class implementing NexusIndexHTMLCustomizer

Tags: nexus

I have a requirement like

1) attach an iframe above the existing nexus oss topmost panel , and the url 
source of that iframe will have to be generated using the url parameters 
coming in as query param . so I have created a java class to generate the 
source url when it is given the HttpServeletRequest object . once I get the 
url I can assign it to a variable and replace source url in the javascript.

so what I planned to do is ,

```
public class CtfButtonBar implements NexusIndexHtmlCustomizer {

.
.
.
 @ Override
    public String getPostBodyContribution( Map<String, Object> context )
    {

        return "<script>jQuery(window).load(function () 
{jQuery('body').find('div:first').prepend('<iframe id=\"myframe\" src=\" " 

+  source url + 

"" >  </iframe>')});</script>";
    }
```

in the above "source url" variable which will be my source attribute of 
iframe need to be generated from the HttpServeletRequest object . so 
basically I need the HttpServeletRequest object inside this class . Is there 
any way I can get this object in this class  CtfButtonBar ?

Comment: I doubt it. I suggest to chat with the developers directly on the hipchat channel linked from http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/participate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to the developers for you and got a bit of a hack as a solution. Here is the suggestions

```
final Request current = Request.getCurrent();
final Reference ref = current.getRootRef() or current.getResourceRef()
```

This uses Restlet and since the Nexus UI is rendered via Restlet it should work - at least as long as the Nexus UI uses Restlet.

Your plugin should have a dependency to the nexus-restlet1x-plugin with the version as the Nexus version you use. A list of them is available on Central via http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.sonatype.nexus.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22nexus-restlet1x-plugin%22

As discussed you can use that code in the method above and therefore get access to the request.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort taken to help me out .BUt how can I use this in CtfButtonBar class (the class which implements NexusIndexHtmlCustomizer ) ? . Please enlighten me on this .